# aspx page object behind a MasterPage object page object?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, master-pages

I have a drop down menu in my MasterPage file that drops down *behind* objects on the aspx page. I have used CSS to apply a z-index of 100 to the masterPage menu and a z-index of -1 to the  tag in the aspx page.  I have added position: relative; in the CSS for each. This is not working. It occurred to me that this might not even be possible to do? But surely others have a drop down menu in their masterPage file and it works correctly (doesn't get hidden by items in the page below). does anyone know if what I am trying to do is possible. and if so, does anyone have any ideas for what I might be doing incorrectly?

MasterPage code:

```
</head>

 <body class="innermainbg">
  <form id="Form1" runat="server">

   <div> 
    <div class="header">        
        <div id="nav" class="clear hideSkiplink nav" >
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="menu" >            
                <staticmenuitemstyle horizontalpadding="20"/>                    

                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Search" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"  Value="Item1" >                            
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Search By Age" NavigateUrl="~/SearchByAge.aspx" Value="Sub Item2"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Search By Price" NavigateUrl="~/SearchByPrice.aspx" Value="Sub Item3"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Search By Date" NavigateUrl="~/SearchByDate.aspx" Value="Sub Item2"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Search By Type" NavigateUrl="~/SearchByType.aspx" Value="Sub Item3"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Advanced Search" NavigateUrl="~/AdvSearch.aspx" Value="Sub Item1"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Get Listed Free!" NavigateUrl="~/GetListed.aspx" Value="Item2">                            
                    </asp:MenuItem>

                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Advertise" NavigateUrl="~/Advertise.aspx" Value="Item2">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Links" NavigateUrl="~/Links.aspx" Value="Sub Item1"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="About" NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Value="Item2">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Terms" NavigateUrl="~/Terms.aspx" Value="Sub Item1"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact" NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx" Value="Item2">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Help" NavigateUrl="~/Help.aspx" Value="Sub Item1"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="FAQs" NavigateUrl="~/FAQs.aspx" Value="Sub Item2"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>                
        </div>            
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>            
    </div>        
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="footerholder">
     <div id="footerContent" class="footer">
        © 2014 Professional Expressions Inc. ClassesnWorkshops.com is a registered Trademark of Professional Expressions Inc. All rights reserved.
     </div>
  </div>
 </form>         

</body>

</html>
```

parial CSS code:
    .back
    {
       position: relative;
       z-index: -1;
    }

```
div.menu
{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;      
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100; 
}
```

ClassResults.aspx page code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="ClassResults.aspx.cs" Inherits="ClassesnWorkshops.ClassResults" %>
```

ZipCode:
           
                 
           Distance:
           
           
                
           
        
        
            lblSearchWords

```
<div align="left" style="background-color: transparent; height: 250px; float:left; width:100%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 50% 50%;">
    <div style="width:13%; float:left; display:inline;" class="rtPad10px">
       <asp:Image ID="spacer1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/spacer_130x18px.png" /> 
    </div>
    <div style="width:69%; height:100%; float:left; display:inline;">           
       <br />                                                         
            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalItemCount" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;                 
            <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentPage" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:Label ID="lblSort" runat="server" Enabled="False" >Sort:</asp:Label> &nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSort" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
            onselectedindexchanged="ddlSort_SelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" > 
            <asp:ListItem Value="Title">Class Title</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="schoolName">School Name</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ClassSubject">Subject</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Miles">Distance</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="lowestCost">Cost (low to high)</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="dateStart">Start Date</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Button ID="btnSort" runat="server" Text="Sort" onclick="btnSort_Click" />
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lblItemsPerPage" runat="server" Enabled="False">Items per page:</asp:Label>&nbsp;
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageSize" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  
                           ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged">
                      <asp:ListItem Text="1" Selected="True" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Text="20" Value="20"></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Text="50" Value="50"></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Text="100" Value="100"></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Text="200" Value="200"></asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />            
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblValidationZip" runat="server" Enabled="False" ForeColor="Red" Text="A valid 5 digit zipCode is required."></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="lblMessage"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMsgTooManyOrTooFew" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br /> 
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptClasses" runat="server" >
           <ItemTemplate>    
              <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblClassesReturned" style="width:99%" >                    
                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
                    <asp:TableCell style="width:15%; text-align:left;">
                       <img src='C:\Users\Teresa\My Webs\ClassesnWorkshops\ClassesnWorkshops\images\logos\<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "logoID") %>.jpg' align="left" alt="School Logo">
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1"  runat="server" style="width:41%; float:left; text-align:left;">
                        Subject: <%# String.Format("{0:0.0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ClassSubject")) %><br />
                        <b>Title: <asp:HyperLink ID="hlClass" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Class.aspx?classID=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ClassID")%>' Text=<%# String.Format("{0:0.0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ClassTitle")) %> Target="_blank" runat="server" /> </b><br></br>
                           <asp:Label ID="lblCostRange" ToolTip="Lowest price usually indicates residence, member or early bird cost. Highest price usually indicates non-residence, non-member or non-earlybird cost." runat="server">
                           Cost Range: <%# String.Format("{0:c}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "lowestCost")) %> - <%# String.Format("{0:c}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "highestCost")) %><br />  
                           </asp:Label> 
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCostNote" runat="server" font-size="8pt">
                                &nbsp;  * Additional Fees or Discounts May Apply. 
                                </asp:Label> 
                                <br />                         
                                <asp:Label ID="lblClassSeason" ToolTip="Season that this class is held." runat="server">
                                <%# String.Format("{0:0.0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ClassSeason")) %> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                </asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblClassYear" ToolTip="Year that this class is held" runat="server"> 
                                <%# String.Format("{0:0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ClassYear")) %> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                </asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="ClassDays" ToolTip="Days of the Week this class is held: M=Monday, T=Tuesday, W=Wednesday, H=Thursday, F=Friday, A=Saturday, S=Sunday" runat="server">
                                <%# String.Format("{0:0.0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ClassDays")) %>  &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                </asp:Label>
                                <%# String.Format("{0:0.0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ClassStartTime")) %><br />
                            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell ID="TableCell2" runat="server" style="width:44%; float:left; text-align:left;">              
                               <b><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/School.aspx" Text=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "schoolName") %> Target="_blank" runat="server" /> </b>
                                -                                       
                                <%# String.Format("{0:0.0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Miles")) %> miles away
                            <br />
                            Campus: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "campus") %><br />
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "street") %> &nbsp;
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "city") %>, &nbsp;
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "state") %> &nbsp;
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "zip") %><br />
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlSchool" NavigateUrl=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "web") %> Text=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "web") %> Target="_blank" runat="server" /> <br>
                            <%-- %><br><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "longDesc")  --%>

                        </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table><br /><hr>
                 <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>            


        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkFirst" runat="server" onclick="LnkFirst_Click">First</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp; &nbsp; <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkPrevious" runat="server" onclick="LnkPrevious_Click">Previous</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp; &nbsp; <asp:Repeater ID="rptPages" runat="server">                   
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnPage" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server">   
                     <%# Container.DataItem %> 
                  </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp; &nbsp;</ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>&nbsp; &nbsp; <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkNext" runat="server" onclick="LnkNext_Click">Next</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp; &nbsp; <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkLast" runat="server" onclick="LnkLast_Click">Last</asp:LinkButton><br />
            <br />
            <%-- 
            <asp:Label ID="lblValidationZip" runat="server" Enabled="False" ForeColor="Red" Text="A valid 5 digit zipCode is required."></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="lblMessage"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMsgTooManyOrTooFew" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            --%>
            </div><div style="width:17%; float:left; display:inline;" ><asp:Image 
            ID="spacer2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/spacer_170x18px.png" /></div></div></asp:Content>
```

Comment: From the client's perspective, there is no msuch thing as a master page. The contents get merged together, the resulting HTML is sent to the client. Whatever problems you are having would still exist even if you were working with a plain .HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your css and html structure using inspect element tool of browser. Open site in browser, right click on it, on bottom of menu you will inspect element option.
This will give you view of complete html and your css. you can edit the css and it will give you instant change on your page.